# If I connect three different capacity lithium batteries in series with a 3S BMS board, When the BMS will stop giving output?

Tags: batteries, series, lithium, bms

If three different capacity batteries are connected in series with a 3S BMS board, when the lowest capacity battery runs out and under voltage occurs of the battery then will the BMS continue giving output or stop giving output at all?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Usually a BMS will monitor the voltage of all cells in the series to make sure none of them are overdischarged. Of course, everything depends on your specific device, but if it has sense wires to each of the cells that usually means it will not allow any cell to drop below a certain voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks again.